# How can I put my Javascript strings on two lines? Like <br> does in HTML

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to output interchanging text (5 sentences that change every few seconds). Everything is working fine until I try splitting each sentence onto two lines. I tried adding a `<br>` line break and I tried using a \ with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
 var quotes = [
    "Line 1 <br> Line 2",
    "Line 1 <br> Line 2",
    "Line 1 <br> Line 2",
    "Line 1 <br> Line 2",
    "Line 1 <br> Line 2",
    ];

    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        $("#textslide").html(quotes[i]);
        if (i == quotes.length)
            i=0;
        else
            i++;
    }, 1 * 1000);
```

Comment: Do you want `\n`? That should break the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `\n` within a string to insert a newline into a string, but that only works if the output is something like in a console. If the output is in HTML, as you already know, the separator must be `<br>`.